# Speed up populate select option with json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have successfully populated a select option list with json.   However there is a lag while it is processed.  I am going to have a list of around 300-400 elements, would anyone have any advice on a better way (best performance) to populate the select list?

The code I am using is:

```
 $.ajax({
'method':'post',
'url':wpajax_initialise_combos, //url to my action
'datatype':'json',
'cache': false,
'success': function( from_data )
{
  var from_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(from_data);
  $.each(from_obj, function(key, value) {
       $('#combobox') 
          .append($("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value",key)
                      .text(value));
      $('#combobox2')
          .append($("<option></option>")
                     .attr("value",key)
                     .text(value));
  });

}
```

});

I wanted to populate the second list based on the output from the first list, but due to performance lag I have decided not to do this and do processing on submit.  Unless there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

common jquery to start with

1. cache element queries
2. detach .. attach pattern to only adjust DOM at attach vs every append

Applied to your code:

```
$.ajax({
'method':'post',
'url':wpajax_initialise_combos, //url to my action
'datatype':'json',
'cache': false,
'success': function( from_data )
{
  var $select1 = $("#combobox");
  var $parent1 = select.parent();
  $select1.detach();

  var $select2 = $("#combobox2");
  var $parent2 = select.parent();
  $select2.detach();

  var from_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(from_data);
  $.each(from_obj, function(key, value) {
     $select1.append($("<option></option>")
                      .attr("value",key)
                      .text(value));
     $select2.append($("<option></option>")
                     .attr("value",key)
                     .text(value));
  });

  $parent1.append($select1);
  $parent2.append($select2);
}
```

Comment: yes this has sped up the process, thanks very much.  I do not know how to test it exactly, but just visually it looks faster.  I think I am getting a delay from my get posts routine bit further down the line, so will investigate that next.